# InnoDB gone missing as database type - has anyone seen this error before?

Tags: database

I'm working on the Drupal 7 site that's currently on Dreamhost.

Since this morning, the site is showing the following error message:

> Error
>   The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again
>   later.
>   Error message PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1286 Unknown table engine 'InnoDB': SELECT expire,
>   value FROM {semaphore} WHERE name = :name; Array ( [:name] =>
>   variable_init ) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of
>   /home/mysite.com/includes/lock.inc). Uncaught exception thrown in
>   shutdown function.
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1286
>   Unknown table engine 'InnoDB': DELETE FROM {semaphore} WHERE
>   (value = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array (
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 7584349655055df9b66b5c9.36234254 )
>   in lock_release_all() (line 269 of
>   /home/mysite.com/includes/lock.inc).

Has anyone seen this sort of error before? Yesterday, my database showed as InnoDB in PHPMyAdmin; today there's nothing showing as "type."

Answer (score 1):

On Debian 6, this can also happen when you change the innodb_log_file_size parameter. Sometimes mysql does not start; other times, it just starts up, but the InnoDB engine is not enabled. The solution is to remove ib_logfiles from /var/lib/mysql and restart mysql.

See [this issue in drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1345236).

Comment: More generally, it happens when InnoDB fails to start, which can be the log file size thing or borked data, check your mysql log.